# Redmine on windows + IIS + mssql server installation

Tags: sql-server, windows, iis, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine on Windows + IIS + mssql server, but i get some errors. I found manual on Github, but it is on Russian and its only manual that I found. And going step by step by this manual I was trying to install Redmine on my computer but got error on trying to create tables in my DB:
"TinyTds::Error: Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist"

Can someone help me with this problem?
Or maybe there is another **free** Project management system for over 50 active users?

Thanks!

P.S.
Link on manul:
https://gist.github.com/sergey-egv/93aa13ada9c8053b6531184967a4b208

Comment: "Adaptive Server" sounds like MySQL - make sure you are following instructions for _SQL Server_, not _MySQL_

Comment: I found some mistake. In database.yml file sections development and test were not commented. But after I've commented them I've got another error: "ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'development' database is not configured. Available: ["production"]"

Comment: Adaptive Server is a Sybase product

Comment: Well I wrote about it, but I shouldn't advertise, however now is packt's black friday, also TinyTds some versions can cause problems. That guy's tutorial seems fine.